# Limit attempts to login with JAAS Basic Authentication

Tags: java, basic-authentication, jaas

I have a custom LDAP loginModule and I need to limit my application to only 3 login atempts.

How can I do this? I tried to throw especifcs LoginExceptions, but the application is still requesting me a login.

Thank You!

Comment: Usually the LDAP directory service will lock the account, not the JAAS module itself.

Comment: @JustinKSU But not even when LDAP block the user password the application stop requesting me.

Depends on the LDAP Error message I need to redirect the user to a page error.

Comment: In general the JAAS module usually doesn't prevent the authentication attempt to call the underlining authentication mechanism (e.g. Active Directory).  However, that said, you could always create your own static java.util.Map of failed login attempts and cut off request.

Comment: @JustinKSU But how can I redirect the response to an error page and stop login requests?

Comment: In your web.xml you can redirect the 401 to a different page.  Alternatively instead of using "j_security_check" you can write your own servlet that calls the login method directly and catches the exception (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html)

Comment: @JustinKSU I made a filter to control de LoginModule, and now I can save the exception and redirect to 401 custom page. Thanks!